# space between my input bars, it just jumbos them all together which is something i dont want

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, apache, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0.1cm">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            Fuel temp probe cap:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" id="temp_prob" style="height: 20px; width: 100px; margin-left: -25px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            Canister:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" id="purge_vol" style="height: 20px; width: 100px; margin-left: -25px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            Fuel Tank:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" id="battery_volt" style="height: 20px; width: 100px; margin-left: -25px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            Manufacture:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" id="battery_cap" style="height: 20px; width: 100px; margin-left: -25px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            Manufacture:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" id="rec_energy" style="height: 20px; width: 100px; margin-left: -25px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            Part Number:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" id="soc_min" style="height: 20px; width: 100px; margin-left: -25px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            Material:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" id="num_of_cycles" style="height: 20px; width: 100px; margin-left: -25px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            SOC min:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <input type="text" id="cop_file" style="height: 20px; width: 100px; margin-left: -25px" disabled="disabled">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Obv I have searched stack overflow, i tried margin bottom and other tips previously given. I guess whoever the previous intern was did write this properly.

Every time i try one of those methods, what ends up happening is that the parameters get messed up. See image below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq8Mn.png)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to put the elements in a different row tag and not all of them in the same row using multiple columns. What causes the lack of spaces between inputs is that all the cols are in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the column (for label) contents get overflowing/wrapped to the next line which inserts the space between input rows, the solution for this will be to increase the label column size, working example below!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-3">
          Fuel temp probe cap:
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" id="temp_prob" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          Canister:
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" id="purge_vol" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          Fuel Tank:
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" id="battery_volt" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          Manufacture:
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" id="battery_cap" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          Manufacture:
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" id="rec_energy" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          Part Number:
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" id="soc_min" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          Material:
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" id="num_of_cycles" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          SOC min:
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
          <input type="text" id="cop_file" />
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2fwrlx?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)